# How to fix unexpected 'else'

Tags: php, mysql

Good day! i'm trying to connect my php program to mysql local host. however i got an error saying

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginpage\log.php on line 6

Here's my program:

```
<?php
    $connect = new mysqli('localhost','root','','login');

    if($Connect->connect_error);{
        die('connectin failed bruh');
    }else
        echo('connect worked');
?>
```

I badly needed your help! Thanks!

Comment: `if($Connect->connect_error);{` that semicolon needs to go away. That terminates the `if`, which means the `else` is unexpected. So it should be `if ($Connect->connect_error) {` instead.

Comment: you not close curly brace of else and semicolon after if condition also need to remove

Comment: remove `;` from `if($Connect->connect_error);{`

Comment: if($Connect->connect_error);  remove **;**

Answer (score 1):

`If` statement body is closed before you start it, you just need to remove semicolon to execute statement of the `if` condition the right code should be

```
if($Connect->connect_error){

............
.............

}
```

Comment: Questions like these should be closed rather than answered - it's a simple typo, and it serves very little purpose to future readers.